# Голодутоляющий / голод утоляющий продукт

Tags: орфография, словообразование, сложные-слова

Как правильно?

> Гречонка, сваренная по-Леопольдовому, — это **голодутоляющий** продукт.

> Гречонка, сваренная по-Леопольдовому, — это голод утоляющий продукт.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как некачественного.

Comment: Не согласна с Вами, *shampar*.  Интересный ведь вопрос — только не совсем правильно сформулированный.  А я его с удовольствием подправлю. И поддержу.

Comment: Чтобы подправить этот вопрос, надо определить его тематику, а этого никто не сделал. Модель образования сложных слов  без соед. гласных используется в языке? А когда? Можно привести примеры таких слов. А почему здесь не используется?  Вот тогда это будет хороший вопрос.

Comment: Ну что же... Давайте тогда закроем этот вопрос! Только потому, что Вы решили, что он **неправильно** сформулирован. И бедное окказиональное слово (интересное ведь слово-то!) не будет использовано. Тематика же ж неправильная!

Comment: Тематика  не обозначена – вот что я говорю.. А это вы написали: "...только не совсем правильно сформулированный. А я его с удовольствием подправлю".  Так подправьте, и он будет правильным. Пока я вижу одно: голодутоляющий нельзя, потому что нельзя.

Comment: Дополнено-с, Лео.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Гречонка, сваренная по-Леопольвому, — это голод утоляющий продукт.***

*Утоляющий (что?) голод* — словосочетание. То есть между ними можно задать вопрос. Это уже док-во раздельного написания.

Второе док-во — это, конечно, то, что этого слова нет ни в одном словаре.

Третье — то, что причастие с существительным так склеивать нельзя. Причастие можно преобразовать в глагол бессуфиксным способом. *Утоляющий — утолять*. Соответственно, *голодутоляющий — голодутолять*. Согласитесь, бред же?

Слитно писать — грубая и, кроме этого, странная ошибка.

**ДОПОЛНЕНО.**

Ни слова *голодутоляющий*, ни слова *голодоутоляющий* не зафиксировано в словарях.

Comment: Практически вся логика вашего ответа разбивается словом "болеутоляющий": https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: @Максим *Третье — то, что причастие с глаголом так склеивать нельзя.* Не поняла — **где** же у нас тут глагол (голод утоляющий)?

Answer (score 4):

Я так понимаю, вас вдохновило слово ***болеутоляющий***?
Ну что ж, если вам так хочется использовать аналогичное слово, то писать нужно *голод**оу**толяющий*, а не *голод**у**толяющий*.
Несмотря на то, что слова *голодоутоляющий* в общепринятом русском языке нет, если бы оно существовало, то было бы образовано именно так.
Примеры: *энерг**о**сберегающий*, *импорт**о**замещающий* и т. д.

Comment: Я поправила Ваш ответ. Надеюсь, Вы не против. Логика словообразования мне нравится. **!**

Comment: Можно сопоставить: лекарство, *жар понижающее* — ***жаропонижающее*** лекарство; напиток, *жажду утоляющий* — ***жаждоутоляющий** напиток (https://translate.academic.ru/%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9/en/ru/).

Comment: Местожительство, времяисчисление, четвертьфинал. Чистое сложение без соед. гласной. Почему нельзя образовать слово так: голодутоляющий? Что и было сделано. Это же объяснить надо. Вот еще: впередсмотрящий, АЗОТСОДЕРЖАЩИЙ Почему не азотосодежащий?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, не против, конечно.

Comment: @Sharon, действительно, а почему бы и не "азотосодержащий"? https://allbeton.ru/library/995/89.html

Comment: В словаре оба слова.  Почему?  Еще : СОЛНЦЕЗАЩИТНЫЙ.

Comment: @Sharon, если отвечать с небольшой долей юмора, то возможно дело было так: однажды химики задали вопрос филологам, и два разных филолога дали два разных ответа. С тех пор так и повелось :)

Comment: Не, там три О сложно выговаривать, не у всех филологов получалось.

Comment: СТИХИ. Гречку кушать всего лучше, если очень голоднущий.

Comment: Ну!.. Если филологам *три О сложно выговаривать*, тогда надо быстренько из лексикона изничтожить слово ***обороноспособность***. Навсегда. Где уж тут какие-то "азоты" и "солнцы".

Comment: Ага, сократить надо: оборонспособность, обспособность, как правильно?

Comment: Никак. Или она есть, или её нет.

Comment: Без разницы. Общеукрепляющая, голодутоляющая, гречка нам поможет во всех случаях.

Comment: И рада бы дальше пошутковать... Но — https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOsIIUhCEbI

Comment: @Sharon Почему _солнцезащитный_ без соед. гласной? Там есть гласная Е. Это не окончание, а соединительная гласная, потому что, когда мы склоняем это слово, склоняется только окончание -ЫЙ-, буква Е остаëтся в порядке.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Логика хорошая, даже отличная, не спорю, но этого слова нет в словарях, я смотрел.

Comment: @Максим Ну да, пылезащитный, солнцезащитный – все одно. Что солнце, что пыль. Почему я не могу считать, что здесь чистое сложение?  Такая модель тоже возможна. Тогда радиозащитный.

Comment: @Максим, вы правы, такого слова действительно нет в словарях. Именно поэтому я написал в своем ответе, чтобы не вводить никого в заблуждение: "Несмотря на то, что слова голодоутоляющий в общепринятом русском языке нет, если бы оно существовало, то было бы образовано именно так". Т.е. здесь действительно идет речь сугубо о том, каким бы было это слово, ЕСЛИ БЫ оно существовало.

Answer (score -1):

Гречонка, сваренная по-Леопольдовому - блюдо, утоляющее голод.
Если речь об утолении голода, то люди бывают разные и утоление голода происходит от разной пищи и разных обстоятельств.
Заметьте: гречонка - продукт, но продукт для продажи либо продукт, который приготовлен для еды (уже не продукт, а блюдо).